# Ruby hash equivalent of JavaScript's object initializer ES6 shorthand

Tags: javascript, ruby, hash, ecmascript-6, shorthand

In JavaScript ES6 we can create objects where variable names become keys like this:

```
> let a = 'aaa'
'aaa'

> let b = 'bbb'
'bbb'

> { a, b }
{ a:"aaa", b:"bbb" }
```

Does Ruby have something equivalent for hashes?

Clarification:
Obviously this question regards the shorthand notation. I'm looking for `{a,b}` not `{a:a,b:b}`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Update: will be in 3.1
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14579#note-14

No, there is no such shorthand notation.

Related proposals:
[#11105](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11105)
[#13137](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13137)

> Rejected. I saw JavaScript new syntax, but I had no sympathy. It doesn't make anything more understandable.
>
> Matz.

Comment: I wish there was, though... :)

Comment: Well, there's not much to understand: if you see an object without the regular key: value syntaxt, then it's the shorthand - it's an useful feature, it tries to make you use consistent names when moving data.

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer** no.

**Longer answer**

Shugo Maeda proposed a patch for this in 2015 (you can read the details about this here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11105).

At the time Matz wasn't into the idea, but might be willing to change his mind in the future.

In the mean time - you can make use of Shugo's patch and patch your own version of Ruby to have ES6 hash literals yourself!

To patch Ruby to add the hashes do the following:

1) Download the patch from here https://gist.github.com/thechrisoshow/1bb5708933d71e0e66a29c03cd31dcc3 (currently works with Ruby 2.5.0)

2) Use RVM to install a patched version of this Ruby. i.e.

```
rvm install 2.5.0 -n imphash --patch imphash.patch
```

Then you can use RVM to select the patched version of Ruby:

```
rvm use 2.5.0-imphash
```

(Imphash is short for implicit hash)

Answer (score 2):

Not built in to the language.  But what do you think of this?

https://gist.github.com/smtlaissezfaire/e81356c390ae7c7d38d435ead1ce58d2

```
def hash_shorthand(source_binding, *symbols)
  hash = {}

  symbols.each do |symbol|
    hash[symbol] = source_binding.local_variable_get(symbol)
  end

  hash
end
```

---

```
$ irb -r './hash_shorthand.rb' 
>> x = 10
>> y = 20
>> 
>> puts hash_shorthand(binding, :x, :y)
{:x=>10, :y=>20}
```

Only downside is that you'll need to pass the binding to get access to the local variables.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from ruby 3.1, it can be done like this:

```rb
x = 1
y = 2

{x:, y:}
# => {:x=>1, :y=>2}
```

Values can be omitted for functions too:

```rb
def x
  1
end

def y
  2
end

{x:, y:}
# => {:x=>1, :y=>2}
```

[Playground](https://wandbox.org/permlink/emtOX02FJgFNzydx)

Answer (score 1):

Although Ruby / Rails doesn't yet support an equivalent to the ES6 shorthand syntax for hashes, there are a few handy idioms already that often come in handy.

## Ruby

Consider the following method:

```
def test_splat(a:, b:, c:)
  [a, b, c].inspect
end
```

`test_splat(a: 4, b: 5, c: 6)` yields `"[4, 5, 6]"`

Although if you already have a hash such as `hash = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`, you can simply call it like this:

`test_splat(hash)` which yields `"[1, 2, 3]"`

#### Further

If you have a sub_hash, you can use it alongside other kwargs using the kwarg splat operator `**`. For example if you have `sub_hash = { a: 1, b: 2 }`, calling:

`test_splat(sub_hash)` yields `ArgumentError: missing keyword: c`

and calling:

`test_splat(sub_hash, c: 3)` yields `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

but using the splat operator `**`, you can do splat the `sub_hash` arg:

`test_splat(**sub_hash, c: 3)` which yields `"[1, 2, 3]"`

For more reading see https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/fun-with-keyword-arguments/

## Rails

The above plus a few extra methods can come in handy for Rails users, particularly in controllers when params are passed in.

Suppose you have an `ActionController::Parameters` object with more attributes than you need and you want a subset. E.g: `{ a: 1, b: 2, d: 4 }`. The `slice` method on `Hash` is very handy here.

First, permit your params:

`permitted_params = params.permit(:a, :b, :d).to_h.symbolize_keys`.

We add `.to_h.symbolize_keys` because `ActionController::Parameters` doesn't support `symbolize_keys`, and kwargs require the args' keys to be symbols, not strings. So the `.to_h` converts it to an `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`, and the `symbolize_keys` converts the hash's keys from strings to symbols.

Now, calling:

`test_splat(**permitted_params, c: 3)` will yield `ArgumentError: unknown keyword: d` as expected since `d` isn't a kwarg for the `test_splat` method. Although using slice achieves what we want here:

`test_splat(**permitted_params.slice(:a, :b), c: 3)` yields `"[1, 2, 3]"`

Answer (score 1):

It has been proposed in [Ruby #15236 - Add support for hash shorthand](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15236) and has unfortunately been rejected for the moment.